Refactoring IEnumerable<T> yield
I have the following code that is used to create simple graphs containing links between nodes
public class Node(string name)
{
    public string Name { get; } = name;
}

public class Link(Node from, Node to)
{
    public Node From { get; } = from;
    public Node To { get; } = to;
}

public class Graph
{
    public List<Node> Nodes = new();
    public List<Link> Links = new();

    public IEnumerable<Node> GetParents(Node node)
    {
        foreach (var link in Links)
        {
            if (link.To == node)
                yield return link.From;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren(Node node)
    {
        foreach (var link in Links)
        {
            if (link.From == node)
                yield return link.To;
        }
    }
}

As there is a large number of nodes and links and due to the graph being highly dynamic, I chose not to store each nodes parents and children on the Node instance itself (a node can have many parents and many children). But instead, have GetParents and GetChildren helper methods on the Graph class.
However, I learnt something new. In that doing this, there is an allocation for each call made to either of these methods due to backing code required for IEnumerable/yield.
As shown in the following test:
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Test
{
    Graph _graph;

    [IterationSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _graph = new Graph();

        Node a = new("A"), b = new("B"), c = new("C");

        _graph.Nodes = [a, b, c];
        _graph.Links = [new Link(a, b), new Link(a, c)];
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Run1()
    {
        _graph.GetParents(_graph.Nodes[1]);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Run2()
    {
        _graph.GetParents(_graph.Nodes[1]);
        _graph.GetParents(_graph.Nodes[1]);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunLoop()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            _graph.GetParents(_graph.Nodes[1]);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void GetChildren_Raw()
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            foreach (var link in _graph.Links)
            {
                if (link.From == _graph.Nodes[1])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

| Method          | Mean        | Error       | StdDev       | Median      | Allocated |
|---------------- |------------:|------------:|-------------:|------------:|----------:|
| Run1            |    673.6 ns |    24.84 ns |     69.66 ns |    700.0 ns |     480 B |
| Run2            |    740.0 ns |    28.49 ns |     81.74 ns |    700.0 ns |     560 B |
| RunLoop         | 31,390.9 ns | 4,295.45 ns | 12,597.80 ns | 35,600.0 ns |   80400 B |
| GetChildren_Raw | 14,674.2 ns |   455.90 ns |  1,322.66 ns | 14,100.0 ns |     400 B |

Other than storing parents and children for each node (something I do not want to do as its a very dynamic graph), how could I implement these methods without allocations?

If you want GetChildren and GetParents not to allocate at all they'll have to return an existing object - which means either having a mutable object (urgh - very, very brittle) or having an object per node (one for children and one for parents) which you've also said you don't want. Those are just fundamental without any implementation concerns. So how do you expect to possibly be able to implement those methods without any allocations? (You could cache the "last returned" one, of course, with a list or something similar... but is that a common use case?)

Is it an option to save the (cached) parent/child information as dictionaries in the Graph class like IDictionary<Node, ISet<Node>>?

@Progman not really, it's a dynamic graph, so any caching would be invalidated too frequently to be of use.

Using yield return changes that method to return a generated class that implements that IEnumerable

List<T> avoids allocations when used in a foreach statement by having its GetEnumerator() method return a struct List<T>.Enumerator that implements IEnumerator<T>.  From the reference source for List<T>:

public class List<T> : IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        => new Enumerator(this);

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        => new Enumerator(this);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       => new Enumerator(this);

    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerator
    {
         // Implementation omitted
    }


As long as the IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() and IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() methods are implemented explicitly, the runtime will pick up the public GetEnumerator() method and insert it into all foreach loops without boxing the returned enumerator.
You can adopt the same approach by wrapping List<Link>.Enumerator in your own enumerator struct with the necessary filtering logic.  First introduce the following enumerable and enumerator inside Graph:
public partial class Graph
{
    public struct NodeEnumerable : IEnumerable<Node>
    {
        readonly Graph graph;
        readonly Node node;
        readonly Func<Link, Node> getFilterNode;
        readonly Func<Link, Node> getReturnNode;
        
        internal NodeEnumerable(Graph graph, Node node, Func<Link, Node> getFilterNode, Func<Link, Node> getReturnNode) =>
            (this.graph, this.node, this.getFilterNode, this.getReturnNode) = (graph, node, getFilterNode, getReturnNode);
        
        public NodeEnumerator GetEnumerator() => new NodeEnumerator(graph.Links.GetEnumerator(), node, GetTo, GetFrom);
        IEnumerator<Node> IEnumerable<Node>.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

        public struct NodeEnumerator : IEnumerator<Node>, IEnumerator
        {
            List<Link>.Enumerator enumerator;
            readonly Node node;
            readonly Func<Link, Node> getFilterNode;
            readonly Func<Link, Node> getReturnNode;

            internal NodeEnumerator(List<Link>.Enumerator enumerator, Node node, Func<Link, Node> getFilterNode, Func<Link, Node> getReturnNode) => 
                (this.enumerator, this.node, this.getFilterNode, this.getReturnNode) = (enumerator, node, getFilterNode, getReturnNode);

            public void Dispose() => enumerator.Dispose();
            public Node Current => getReturnNode(enumerator.Current);
            void IEnumerator.Reset() => enumerator.Reset();

            object? IEnumerator.Current => Current;

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    if (getFilterNode(enumerator.Current) == node)
                        return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class EnumeratorExtensions
{
    // Use to avoid boxing enumerator structs that implement Reset explicitly
    public static void Reset<TEnumerator>(ref this TEnumerator enumerator) where TEnumerator : struct, IEnumerator => 
        enumerator.Reset();
}

Then modify GetParents() and GetChildren() as follows:
public partial class Graph
{
    public List<Node> Nodes = new();
    public List<Link> Links = new();

    public NodeEnumerable GetParents(Node node) => new NodeEnumerable(this, node, GetTo, GetFrom);

    public IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren(Node node) => new NodeEnumerable(this, node, GetFrom, GetTo);
    
    // Make these delegates static to avoid allocations
    readonly static Func<Link, Node> GetFrom = static n => n.From;
    readonly static Func<Link, Node> GetTo = static n => n.To;
}

And now foreach loops through the parents and children will no longer allocate memory (as run in .NET 8)
Environment version: .NET 8.0.8 (8.0.8), Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0

| Method          | Mean        | Error     | StdDev      | Median      | Allocated |
|---------------- |------------:|----------:|------------:|------------:|----------:|
| Run1            |    200.0 ns |   0.00 ns |     0.00 ns |    200.0 ns |     400 B |
| Run2            |    282.3 ns |  13.30 ns |    38.37 ns |    300.0 ns |     400 B |
| RunLoop         | 25,766.3 ns | 710.75 ns | 2,004.68 ns | 25,100.0 ns |     400 B |
| GetChildren_Raw | 18,692.0 ns | 606.99 ns | 1,661.62 ns | 18,500.0 ns |     400 B |

Notes:

The optimization that List<T>.GetEnumerator() returns a mutable struct which the .NET runtime will notice and use has been around since .NET 2.

If one upcasts a List<T> to an IList<T> the optimization will be lost and the list enumerator will be boxed.

However LINQ avoids this boxing by checking whether incoming enumerables are actually lists then wrapping their enumerators in a specialized containing enumerator that declares the list enumerator explicitly, see e.g. Enumerable.Where().  If you are frequently passing the enumerables returned by GetParents() and GetChildren() into some LINQ expressions you may want to do something similar.

I used a single struct for both GetParents() and GetChildren() by passing in static delegates for the From and To logic.  For absolutely maximal performance, if you wanted to avoid the delegate callback you could separate enumerators for each.

For another performance tweak, you may want to investigate whether avoiding use of the readonly keyword for fields results in a speedup.  For why this might be true see Micro-optimization: the surprising inefficiency of readonly fields by Jon Skeet.



A lot of effort here, nice answer; minor thing: a lot of APIs now use [ReadOnly] on members that don't change state, which avoids a lot of the readonly copy problem (on modern runtimes)

Thanks!  I'll read up on [ReadOnly].

ReadOnlyAttribute is a member of System.ComponentModel and as such would not really appear to be a general-use attribute. I can't find any C# documentation which states that this attribute can affect the compile-time or JIT code - am I missing something?

Really appreciate this. Not going to lie, its probably over my head, but will do my best to  make sense of it.

@jessejbweld - glad to help.  By the way, the suggestion by JonasH to replace the flat list with a dictionary might be worth considering.  You might be able to combine Two-way / bidirectional Dictionary in C#? with c# dictionary How to add multiple values for single key? to create a bidirectional collection that tracks multiple children for each parent.

If you're looking to completely optimise out the allocation of the return of the functions GetParents and GetChildren, then don't return an implictly allocated reference object. You can effectively perform a callback using a lambda action on the items instead.
    public void ForEachParent(Node node, Action<Link> action)
    {
        foreach (var link in Links)
        {
            if (link.To == node)
                action(link);
        }
    }

Usage example:
   _graph.Links.ForEachParent(_graph.Nodes[1], (x) => Console.WriteLine(x));

NB. This is a very simple example to show its usage; we are indeed making an allocation on the action. However this could importantly be easily refactored either to outside the for loop, or even outside the class instance and made static if need be.
Optimisation balance
Of course with this level of optimisation, you are sacrificing flexibility; the function may have to be customised to do something else based on the caller's requirements. It's an intrusive optimisation. It's not as flexible as returning an IEnumerable.
There is a use case for doing things like this; but as with any type of optimisation at this level, its intrusiveness, rigidity and comparative maintenance overhead has to be carefully weighed against the requirement for how much of a CPU cost benefit you'll see and how much this CPU cost benefit is required.
Further discussion
If we're getting to this level of optimisation, beginning to sacrifice developer usability for pure iteration speed, consider avoiding the use of foreach. It's not as fast as an indexed for.
Also in my example I said use a lambda. It's even faster if you use a "hard" function instead of a lambda.

Thanks, I did actually experiment with lambdas as they occurred to me right after posting the question (as is usually the case for me :P ). They work well, but the code looks very odd now, so requires extra comments to explain the reasoning ... which is always a bad sign ... Might revert it :P

Indeed if code requires comments that's a bad smell. If you do use a lambda, name it functionally on a previous line. Or possibly consider a local function. Or sometimes it's better to use a named, "real" function; the solution I provided will take any of the above and implicitly instantiate the Action. You can even make the Action a member to stop having to instantiate it every time, too. I don't think you're going to find an alternative answer.

I think you are missing the bigger problem here. Each time you want to get the children or parent to a node you need to iterate over all the links in the graph. This is a much bigger problem than just a few allocations once the graph size starts to get large.
A much more typical solution would be to use a dictionary to store the links:
Dictionary<Node, List<Node>> links = new ();

This allow you to quickly find all the connected nodes. To add bidirectional links just add each node to each others lists. This approach also conveniently avoids the allocation problems.
You could make this dictionary into a separate helper class with methods to automatically create the list when adding the first link for a node. This is sometimes called a MultiValueDictionary, and can be a useful collection in many circumstances.

I explained in the question that I did not want to cache anything as the state changes too frequently for it to be of any real benefit, plus there is some logic that is very specific to the problem I am solving which just doesn't work well with caching. In hindsight I could have asked this question without any of the graph stuff. It should have just been, "Can you implement a yield method without allocations" :)

@jessejbweld I really do not understand what you mean by "caching". This would not be a cache, this would be a entire description of the graph. Other answers have covered the allocation issues, but when asking you should mention the actual application to avoid XY-problems. Using an O(n) algorithm, even just as an example, when a O(1) will do makes me wonder if you are spending your time on the right problem.

It's a dynamic graph, the links are frequently changing, so I would need to keep updating the dictionary you suggested.

@jessejbweld Yes, but dictionary addition and removal are both O(1). While removal from a list is O(n), so the only time a list would be better is if you only add links, never do traversal or removal. You could also consider using a HashSet instead of List as the inner collection. A custom collection would likely do even better, but require more knowledge about exactly how this graph is modified.

Why are you mentioning removing from a list?

@jessejbweld because removal is a common type of change. And the only way you can remove links in your example is by using List.Remove. If you are only ever add links, never removing or modifying, you probably want to use other terms than "dynamic" or "changing".

Yes - I am not removing or adding links from the list, but simply changing the To/From. I appreciate this wasn't clear in the code (my mistake), which is why I said previously that in hindsight, I should have asked the question without any of the simplified graph example code. The question was supposed to be targeted simply at the allocation aspect.

@jessejbweld Well, my point still stands, A dictionary support O(1) time for all required operations. A list of links require O(n) for finding links, so will be far inferior as the graph grows large.
